# What are the lodash combinations to achieve the below scenario?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I get below data from twitter in which you can see it has multilevel array in it.I need a single array which has all the objects in it.You can find below how i need the data to be shown.

```
[
    [{
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
    }, {
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
    }],

    [{
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
    }, {
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
    }],

    [{
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
    }, {
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
    }]
]
```

but I need to loop only single array like this having all the data combined in single array.

```
[{
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
     }, {
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
    {
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
    }, {
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
    }, {
        "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
        "id": "asdfasdf",
        "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
    }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`_.flatten(arr, isDeep)`](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten)

> Flattens a nested array. If `isDeep` is true the array is recursively flattened, otherwise it’s only flattened a single level.

```
var flattenedArr = _.flatten(arr);
```

If your array is nested then use the `true` as second argument for deep flatten.

```
var flattenedArr = _.flatten(arr, true);
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/g5odyfLx/)

```js
var arr = [
  [{
    "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
    "id": "asdfasdf",
    "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
  }, {
    "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
    "id": "asdfasdf",
    "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
  }],

  [{
    "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
    "id": "asdfasdf",
    "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
  }, {
    "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
    "id": "asdfasdf",
    "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
  }],

  [{
    "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
    "id": "asdfasdf",
    "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
  }, {
    "created_at": "Tue May 19 04:36:36 +0000 2015",
    "id": "asdfasdf",
    "id_str": "ASdfasdfasdf"
  }]
];

console.log(_.flatten(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```